# Does typescript have an option to disallow "any" when declaring or cast/conversion?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

I'm using TypeScript version 1.8.10 in Visual Studio 2015.

In tsconfig.json I have those settings as

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "target": "es6",
  "module": "system",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "removeComments": true,
  "noImplicitAny": true,
  "noEmitOnError": false,
  "noImplicitUseStrict": false,
  "declaration": false,
  "inlineSourceMap": true,
  "inlineSources": true
},
```

I'm wondering is is there a setting that disallow the use of "any" and force us to use datatype such as number, string, etc. instead of "any"?

Answer (score 4):

You could use TSLint in conjunction with TypeScript and set the [`no-any` flag](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-any/). See https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint

There's also ESLint with the [`no-explicit-any`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-explicit-any.md) rule.