# Why doesn't TypeScript compiler complain when returning any as type?

Tags: typescript

I would like TypeScript compiler to complain if my function returns type `any` instead of my declared return type.

Is this possible?

```typescript
function myFunction():number{
  return 'a string that is not a number' as any;
}

//  ↑ I would like to throw an error in the compiler
```

Here the problem is that this function will return a string instead of a number, as expected.

I would like to use type `any` in other functions, so I don't want to disable the type `any`.

**EDIT**

This was just an example. My real problem is that I am using some libraries that have return type `any`. And so the implementation doesn't complain.

```typescript
function myFunction():number{
  return anotherFunctionThatHasReturnTypeAny();
}

//  ↑ I would like to throw an error in the compiler
```

Is it possible to make the compiler fail if the return type is `any`?

Comment: You cannot, it's a fundamental property of a TS type system that `any` is assignable to any other type. "I would like to use type any in other functions" --- you probably just better don't.

Comment: the problem here is that my function is returning a string instead of a number and the compiler doesn't throw an error. I am asking why?

Comment: Because you included a type assertion. If that's not what you want, *don't do that*.

Comment: @nbl7 "my function is returning a string" --- your `return` statement is returning not a string, but an `any`, and `any` is assignable to a `number`, hence - there is no contradiction.

Comment: Of course this is an example. My function actually use some libraries that return a type any, and so I don't know if I am implementing well my code.

Comment: The whole *point* of `any` is that it's compatible with any other type, so no.

Comment: `typescript-eslint` has a rule called [no-unsafe-return](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-unsafe-return.md) which might help here.

Comment: Hey buddy! Is it possible for you to stop using `any` completely? Because that is the better solution. Use of `any` is considered an anti-pattern.

Comment: That is what I wish to do. But some libraries that I am using have functions that returns `any` unfortunately.

Comment: @emlai Thanks that would probably work but I cannot find a way to implement it in Vim.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does typescript have an option to disallow “any” when declaring or cast/conversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36898828/does-typescript-have-an-option-to-disallow-any-when-declaring-or-cast-conversi).  If you do not consider this a duplicate please add distinguishing details.  Good luck!

Comment: This is not a duplicate since I don't want to disable the type `any`. I want the compiler to throw an error if the return type of the function implementation is `any`. So that I force the developer to return the declared return type of the function.